# Easiest Way to Find XPath Of An Element

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping, scrapy

I am learning Scrapy and wondering is there some existing tool - probably Chrome Maybe Web Developer or Firefox plug-in to quickly get the XPath of a web element. Or the best way to go is learn Xpath and build the Xpath yourself from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Chrome**...

There are plugins such as [**XPath Helper**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) that can produce an XPath to a given element on an HTML page.  You can also right-click on an element in a page and pull up its position in the Elements tab.  From there, you can right-click and select **Copy XPath**.

And to really learn XPath, I'd recommend directly writing your own from scratch.  You can select nodes directly from the console by using **`$x()`**.  For example, here's how to select the search form on this page:

```
> $x("//form[@id='search']")

[<form id=​"search" action=​"/​search" method=​"get" autocomplete=​"on">​…​</form>​]
```

Note that the `form` element will be expandable interactively in the console.

Here's how to select all of the text nodes on this page that contain the word *Thanks*:

```
> $x("//text()[contains(.,'Thanks')]")

["Thanks a lot!", "Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!"]
```

Note that you'll get more matches than I originally did if you try it on this page.  Strange loop.

Here's how to select the number of votes this answer has received:

```
> $x("//div[@id='answer-18839594']//span[@class='vote-count-post ']/text()")

["0"]
```

Note an unfortunate robustness issue where `vote-count-post` must include a trailing space to mirror the current source.  Note also the unfortunately low value returned by that XPath. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "the XPath of an element". There are a variety of paths you might be interested in. The shortest machine-executable path is probably along the lines `*[3]/*[1]/*[2]`. The most readable path is something like `chap[3]/section[1]/para[2]`; but this may be dependent on the namespace context. For a context-free path you might want `*[local-name()='chap' and namespace-uri()='...'][1]/*[local-name()='section' and namespace-uri()='...'][3]`. But sometimes when people ask for "the path", they just want `chap/section/para`, that is, a path that selects many elements including the target element. But for some purposes, the most usable XPath expression might be `id('Intro')`.